# Incorrect Syntax near ';' (Microsoft SQL Server Error 102)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sccm

First off, I have been searching all over for an answer to this, and I am also new to SQL coding, so please bear with me.

I am trying to discover the current health status of client machines in SCCM 2012r2 with a custom report, please see code below:

```
SELECT     v_r_system.name0                                       AS 'Computer Name', 
           v_gs_antimalwarehealthstatus.lastquickscanage          AS 'Days since last quick scan',
           v_gs_antimalwarehealthstatus.lastfullscanage           AS 'Days Since Last Full Scan',
           v_gs_antimalwareinfectionstatus.computerstatus         AS 'Current Status', 
           v_gs_antimalwareinfectionstatus.lastcleaneddectiontime AS 'Last Cleaned' 
FROM       v_gs_antimalwarehealthstatus 
INNER JOIN v_gs_antimalwarehealthstatus 
INNER JOIN v_r_system 
ON         v_gs_antimalwarehealthstatus.resourceid = v_r_system.resourceid 
INNER JOIN v_gs_antimalwareinfectionstatus;
```

When I try it out in Report Builder 3.0 I keep getting following error:

[image: Error 102]

I can't seem to find the problem, it's driving me crazy...

Anyway, anything you can do to point me in the right direction would be great.

Cheers

Comment: Where are the `ON`-clauses of the `Joins`?

Comment: `INNER JOIN v_gs_antimalwareinfectionstatus;` - add join condition

Comment: You miss the on clause in some inner join here: `INNER JOIN v_gs_antimalwarehealthstatus` 
 and `INNER JOIN v_gs_antimalwareinfectionstatus`

Comment: inner join [something] on [first bit's field] = [second bit's field]

Comment: And i guess `FROM       v_gs_antimalwarehealthstatus 
INNER JOIN v_gs_antimalwarehealthstatu`s` should be only `FROM       v_gs_antimalwarehealthstatus `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just missed the `ON Clause` in the statement, also you can use `table alias` as it makes the query look clean.

```
SELECT     v_r_system.name0                                       AS 'Computer Name', 
           v_gs_antimalwarehealthstatus.lastquickscanage          AS 'Days since last quick scan',
           v_gs_antimalwarehealthstatus.lastfullscanage           AS 'Days Since Last Full Scan',
           v_gs_antimalwareinfectionstatus.computerstatus         AS 'Current Status', 
           v_gs_antimalwareinfectionstatus.lastcleaneddectiontime AS 'Last Cleaned' 
FROM       v_gs_antimalwarehealthstatus AWT
INNER JOIN v_r_system VRS
    ON  AWT.resourceid = VRS.resourceid 
INNER JOIN v_gs_antimalwareinfectionstatus AWI 
    ON [Place the Matching columns here];
```

Comment: You'd need to use the aliases in the `SELECT` clause as well know since the names like `v_gs_antimalwarehealthstatus` will no longer be in scope.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the answers guys.it is now glaringly obvious that I need to go learn some more, so I bought a book, and I'm gonna study up. Thanks again guys.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever oops my mistake missed the same in the `SELECT` thanks for the catch :)

Answer (score 0):

On whith columns do you join at the last table v_gs_antimalwareinfectionstatus?
just add conditions in an ON-Clause and it should work fine

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two Problems in your query. first:

```
FROM       v_gs_antimalwarehealthstatus 
INNER JOIN v_gs_antimalwarehealthstatus
```

Why the inner join with it selfs? I think it is unnecessary and should be simply:

```
FROM       v_gs_antimalwarehealthstatus
```

The second one is that in the last join the `ON` condition is missing:

```
INNER JOIN v_gs_antimalwareinfectionstatus ON ... ....;
```

So the `FROM .. JOIN` part must look like:

```
FROM       v_gs_antimalwarehealthstatus 
INNER JOIN v_r_system 
ON         v_gs_antimalwarehealthstatus.resourceid = v_r_system.resourceid 
INNER JOIN v_gs_antimalwareinfectionstatus
ON v_gs_antimalwareinfectionstatus.<column> = <otherTable>.<column>
```